# printing a url with variables

Tags: javascript

**TLDR**

I want to print this

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://nyc.mymusicwebsite.com/coolband/1222
"/>
```

where

```
var termsText = nyc
var deliurl = http://nyc.mymagazine.com/coolband/122
deliurl2[1] = mymagazine
deliurl[2] = .com/coolband/122
```

(deliurl is split at .)
I have this code so far which almost works, This is the problem

```
document.write('<link rel=cononical"'+" ""href="http:"//"""+termsText+"."+deliurl2[1]+deliUrl[2]'"/>');
```

I have a drupal website that creates duplicate content for every post,

every post creates multiple pages

```
http://nyc.mymusicwebsite.com/coolband/1222
http://national.mymusicwebsite.com/coolband/1222
http://seatle.mymusicwebsite.com/coolband/1222
http://la.mymusicwebsite.com/coolband/1222
```

though only one post is visible on the website the other posts are getting indexed.

the posts above are all tagged in a div with the region they are assigned and visible on the website.

I want to print the google rel conical link, linking to the conincal post.  this post would have the subdomain identical to the pages tag in the div.

I have done everything except printing the url

consider the following code

```
    //find tag in page for pattern match
    var termsText = $("#terms").find("ul li:last").text(); 

    //get window location url to test agains pattern
    var deliUrl=window.location.href


    //test pattern
    var patt1=new RegExp(termsText);


    //split url at first period to isolate everything after the subdomain
    var deliUrl2=deliUrl.split('.');


    //if pattern is NOT in url print google conical tag pointing to propper subdomain
    if (patt1.test(deliUrl));

    {
        //print subdomain as "terms" and rest of url
        document.write('<link rel=cononical"'+" ""href="+termsText+"."+deliurl2[1]+deliUrl[2]'"/>');

}
```

Comment: Can you explain more about why you want to do this? I feel like you are missing the forest but for the trees.

Comment: we have 3 programmers working on this it's a quick fix for now we only want one subdomain (the one with the matching tag in the post's content) to be indexed. This has been delegated to me.

Comment: I just need help with the syntax of my document.write() statement I am new to javascript and syntax is a weakness

Comment: I don't think that dynamically writing a canonical tag into your document is going to be picked up by search engines. I think you need to fix it server-side or just block indexing of extra sites with a robots.txt

Comment: I should also add that relying on canonical is unreliable. It is essentially at the search engines discretion to rely on your canonical tag. They could use, they could not. They could use one of the pages you `don't` want as the canonical.

Comment: have you seen this? http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139394

Comment: From the faq on that page - "This new option lets site owners `suggest` the version of a page that Google should treat as canonical. Google will take this into account, in conjunction with other signals, when determining which URL sets contain identical content, and calculating the most relevant of these pages to display in search results." The keyword is SUGGEST. Therefore unreliable.

Comment: it's a cheap fix but I am trying to write something quick in javascript for damage control while we figure out the much bigger and complicated issues on the backend. I don't know much about .htaccess this seems like something I can do for now

Comment: I mean your right but I want to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/TDCEN/1/

I used your hardcoded values. There were a number of things wrong in your document.write method. Javascript is case sensitive so you have to make sure things match. Be careful with your quotes. You can go multiline in js, so do as I did and break things up in a sensical manner. I changed the first `<` to `>` because it otherwise the output could not be shown.

I still don't think this will work though. I doubt the search engines are reading head information modified by js. Good luck though. Definitely look into robots.txt file. You can basically say don't index these pages. This affects SEO since they won't be index at all, but that sounds like what you want.

```
var termsText = 'nyc';
var deliurl = 'http://nyc.mymagazine.com/coolband/122';
var part1 = 'mymagazine';
var part2 = '.com/coolband/122';

document.write(
    '>link rel="canonical" href="http://' +
    termsText +
    '.' +
    part1 +
    part2 +
    '" />'             
);
```

Comment: the reason robots.txt has not been implemented is because this is a blog, new content is created every day and every post has this issue.   there are thousands of past posts with duplicates as well. If there was a similar way to automate it for all past and future posts as is done here that would be great.

Comment: I see. Yes, that would be a pain. I also feel the pain of not having choices. Despite all my canonical bashing I implemented it at work after the marketing folks wouldn't relent. Its caused problems, but at least I don't get hassled =)

Comment: Maintainability is a problem. - http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=canonical+problems#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=off&source=hp&q=the+canonical+tag+is+bad&pbx=1&oq=the+canonical+tag+is+bad&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=2419l4698l0l4828l24l15l0l3l3l0l161l1243l5.7l12l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=1044cc90155403b5&biw=1136&bih=753